# How to set SRCREV for git tag in Yocto?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to fetch specific tag from a git repository, however I keep running into problems with SRCREV.

When I use the tag's commit hash like this:

```
SRC_URI = "git://example.com/repo.git;protocol=https;branch=main;tag=${PV}"
SRCREV = "2bd3465aa7eac0d2de55c9918ce66cac1bcc048f"
```

I get the following error (`6.44` is the version from `${PV}` and a tag name):

```
Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Conflicting revisions (2bd3465aa7eac0d2de55c9918ce66cac1bcc048f from SRCREV and 6.44 from the url) found, please specify one valid value', None)
```

If I then specify SRCREV to be the same as in URL (`SRCREV = "${PV}"`) I get this:

```
Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError("Recipe uses a floating tag/branch '6.44' for repo 'example.com/repo.git' without a fixed SRCREV yet doesn't call bb.fetch2.get_srcrev() (use SRCPV in PV for OE).", None)
```

I'm not sure what the `use SRCPV in PV for OE` means but if I then do `PV = "${SRCPV}"` I quite understandably get an error regarding cyclical variable expansion:

```
The variable dependency chain for the failure is: SRCPV -> PV -> SRCREV -> SRCPV -> PV -> BP -> FILESPATH
```

I found many solutions for getting the latest commit from a branch, but seemingly nothing regarding properly setting up specific tag. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the tag in the SRC_URI then you don't need a SRCREV, but latest releases really don't like you using "floating" references for determinism reasons.  A tag is a floating reference, because you can move the tag.

If you want to checkout 6.44 then identify the SHA that tag points at, and just set SRCREV to that sha.

Comment: If I don't specify SRCREV at all I get the `Recipe uses a floating tag/branch '6.44' for repo 'example.com/repo.git' without a fixed SRCREV` error again. I would like to use tag name, since then I can do `tag=${PV}` and tag name seems more descriptive than just SHA. Is there a way to do it? I could always use release tarball, it works, but then I'm running into problems with unstable GitHub/GitLab archive URLs, which seems like more of a problem than SRCREV.

Comment: The archive tarball URLs are not "release tarballs" as they will be autogenerated and are not reproducible. The correct way is to specify the SHA.

Comment: It's definitely not ideal, but it seems the raw SHA is the way to go. Thanks!